# put button inside qtablewidget cells

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am a beginner and I designed two windows with QT Designer

I have a table that I want to put a button in the second and third columns and clicking on them will open a window.
I wrote the code, but only if the last button is clicked, the "Form" window opens and the other buttons do nothing.
And that I want the buttons to be in the center of the column. I could not do it with "setTextAlignment".
Can you tell me what to do?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(567, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 567, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "transactions"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "more"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.openGLWidget = QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget(Form)
        self.openGLWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 382, 282))
        self.openGLWidget.setObjectName("openGLWidget")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    f = Ui_Form()
    f.setupUi(Form)
    
    # In the main program, the data is read from the database.
    data = ['ahmed','joy','joly']
    ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data) + 1)
    print(* data, sep='-')
    for i,ii in enumerate(data):
        itm = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(ii)
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,0,itm)
        ui.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("...")
        ui.btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 25))
        ui.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+")
        ui.btn2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(25, 25))
        ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, 1, ui.btn)
        ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, 2, ui.btn2)
    
    ui.btn2.clicked.connect(Form.show)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Only one question should be asked in each post. Your first problem is because `ui.btn2` is overwritten every time the for loop iterates, so you are only connecting the last button; move the `ui.btn2.clicked.connect(Form.show)` line at the same indentation level of the for loop. Note that setting instance attributes in for loops is usually wrong and pointless in these cases, so just use a local variable. You should also not edit or merge files created with pyuic, but properly follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Yes, it will be overwritten correctly. How can I add buttons for each cell and create a signal for all those buttons?
I apologize if I do not understand your explanation well. I am a beginner. @musicamante

Comment: I already told you: move that line at the same indentation level of the previous `for` loop block.

Comment:  thank you very much for your help @musicamante